# Windows 10 explorer Libraries location corrupted

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I have a brand new computer with an SSD and an HDD both plugged in with SATA. Windows is installed on the SSD (C:) and the HDD (E:) is practically empty.

I want the default windows libraries (i.e Downloads, Documents, Pictures etc.) to all be located on the HDD in order to save space on the SSD. I moved the downloads folder there using the properties menu (in the Location tab), but I guess I entered the Documents Folder location wrong and now it thinks the whole disk is that folder, and I can't restore it to default - I get an "invalid path" error.

Also, I tried right-clicking the Libraries folder and then restore to default with no help.

What it looks like:

[image]

Will formatting the HDD help? Any other advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting should help, otherwise, try a system restore. Make sure you define an actual folder next time. Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QG4LXw4Nd5U

Comment: Formatting didn't help. I'm resetting the system now. Too bad all the work I've put in it today went to waste...

Comment: @ScubaDiving No reset required. Either System Restore or the registry fix in this page should resolve this problem. [Windows 10 User Shell Folders Restore Default Paths](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-shell-folders-paths-defaults-restore/)

Comment: Well I didn't have a save point, and if I had - it was without all the heavy software I installed. Anyway, I've reset it and it works fine now - thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You might be able to use System Restore to roll the system back to solve this problem, if there is a restore point of course.